Error while remote debugging using gdb debugger on VSCode：Can't open /tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Cmd-ydya5g2b.rmi
I use vscode on mac to remotely connect to the server and use gdb for debugging. After I configure the json file, I always get the following problem when I click the debug button. It has been bothering me for several days.
{
      "name": "coremark-riscv64-xs_o2_x10",
      "type": "cppdbg",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "/data/workspace/build/RISCV/gem5.debug",
      "args": [
        "--outdir=./coremark_output/",
        "./configs/example/fs.py",
        "--caches",
        "--l2cache",
        "--xiangshan-system",
        "--cpu-type=DerivO3CPU",
        "--mem-type=DRAMsim3",
        "--dramsim3-ini=xiangshan_DDR4_8Gb_x8_2400.ini",
        "--mem-size=8GB",
        "--cacheline_size=64",
        "--l1i_size=64kB",
        "--l1i_assoc=8",
        "--l1d_size=128kB",
        "--l1d_assoc=8",
        "--l1d-hwp-type=SMSPrefetcher",
        "--l1-to-l2-pf-hint",
        "--l2_size=2MB",
        "--l2_assoc=8",
        "--l2-hwp-type=WorkerPrefetcher",
        "--l2-to-l3-pf-hint",
        "--l3cache",
        "--l3_size=16MB",
        "--l3_assoc=16",
        "--l3-hwp-type=WorkerPrefetcher",
        "--maxinsts=40000010",
        "--enable-difftest",
        "--generic-rv-cpt=/data/landun/coremark/coremark-riscv64-xs_o2_x10.bin"
      ],
      "stopAtEntry": false,
      "cwd": "/data/landun/workspace/",
      "environment": [
        {
          "name": "NEMU_HOME",
          "value": "/gem5_common/xs-env/NEMU"
        },
        {
          "name": "XS_PROJECT_ROOT",
          "value": "/gem5_common/xs-env"
        },
        {
          "name": "AM_HOME",
          "value": "/gem5_common/xs-env/nexus-am"
        },
        {
          "name": "NOOP_HOME",
          "value": "/gem5_common/xs-env/XiangShan"
        }
      ],
      "externalConsole": false,
      "MIMode": "gdb",
      "setupCommands": [
        {
          "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
          "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "description": "Set Disassembly Flavor to Intel",
          "text": "-gdb-set disassembly-flavor intel",
          "ignoreFailures": true
        },
        {
          "text": "set output-radix 16"
        }
      ]
    }

After I enter docker and debug, the following problems always occur
root@VMware:/data/workspace#  /usr/bin/env /bin/sh /tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Cmd-gm2ebrqv.3h5 
/bin/sh: 0: Can't open /tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Cmd-gm2ebrqv.3h5

And the suffix after cmd will always change.
Thank you in advance, I really appreciate the help!
I have been searching for related questions but it seems that there is no similar problem to mine. I have been modifying json files and other things.
